# How to open a embed movie from mydabase using PHP

Tags: url, embed

This is a clone site I make like www.teensnow.com. That works pretty good, but I don't wont open the target page.And this case is www.xhamster.com. So I wont open a page my and embed the movies in that page! Please take a look on the script ?>

```
<?php
$coneta = mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());
$banco = mysql_select_db('database');
?>
```

this layer is the target where the thumbs stay

```
<div align="center" id="box">

   <div align="center" id="carrosel" style="width: 90%">

         <?php // here is the pagination

     $totalthumbsperpage = 64;

     $page     = (isset($_GET['pagina'])) ? (int)$_GET['pagina'] : 1;

     $begin     = ($totalthumbsperpage * $page) - $totalthumbsperpage;

     $sql = "SELECT * FROM rowname ORDER BY thumb DESC LIMIT $begin,       $totalthumbsperpage";
$qr = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
while($ln = mysql_fetch_assoc($qr)){

?>
```

here is where the thumbs is showing on a page. But like you can see, I have the url open in a new page, that's good. But that urls is out of site my site and I want open the movie embedded on a page my.

```
<a href="<?php echo $ln['url'];?><img src="<?php echo $ln['thumb'];?></a>

<?php           

}

?>


</div>

<div align="center">

<?php   

$sqlTotal = "SELECT thumb FROM rowname";

$qrTotal  = mysql_query($sqlTotal) or die(mysql_error());

$numTotal = mysql_num_rows($qrTotal);

$totalPagina= ceil($numTotal/$totalthumbsperpage);

            for($i = 1; $i <= $totalPagina; $i++){

        if($i == $pagina)

            echo $i";}?>

</div><br><br>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Okay so I would look at the process this way: Retrieve link to video on the database/host. Then use that link and use javascript or random pages to set the dcoument html embed tag with the acquired link from the db.

Comment: Hi! So, if I want, I can create a new row on the database with the embed code. My idea is: when I click on thumb, open a new page and that page must take the href embed code from that thumb. But I don't know how can I do this! I can´t remember, I stop working with computer about 5 years ago, and now I must learne everthing again.

Comment: Okay so you're basically trying to create a tube site right? Why not create the page and row, when a user uploads the video?

Comment: Weel, I have a AVS script, but by now I have no money to spend in a server.So please, take a look in this site (www.sextubevideo.eu or wwww.sexhot.pt)Is a very simple way to make some money with ads.So I use the contents of xhamter.com and can post 5000 videos a time!But,If I could open the video embeded in a page,my visitors would not come out of my site and I would have more space for ads.I have another site when I use AVS script,but the users can not upload videos becouse I don´t have access to the server root. That way I need post videos one by one on daschboard. (www.just4ladys.eu).

Comment: I am try this code, I think the way is here! by now I can conect to db and get the array! After this is how to embed the url on a new page.<?php 
   mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()); 
   mysql_select_db("fodas") or die(mysql_error()); 
   $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM embed") 
   or die(mysql_error()); 
   Print "<table border cellpadding=3>"; 
   while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
   { 
   Print "<tr>"; 
   print "<th>Name:</th> <td>".$info['url'] . "</td> "; 
   Print "<th>Pet:</th> <td>".$info['thumb'] . " </td></tr>"; 
   } 
   Print "</table>"; 
?>

Comment: you need to create a  html page using php